# Dead spots on touchscreen: Could it be related to software corruption?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, hardware, touchscreen

I have a Sony Xperia P running stock Android 4.1.2. A few days ago, my phone started misbehaving and I found some dead spots on its touchscreen. I can't click on some of the areas. Could it be a software problem? I've already tried a factory reset but it didn't work. I've installed CWM recovery image and taken a complete NANDroid backup. Before flashing a new ROM, I wanted to make sure if I'm headed in the right direction. I'm not sure if my screen digitizer is damaged or what. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing flash stock ROM to check the issue and most probably in these cases its a hardware fault as you described you have dead spots on touch they can be due to pressure of some kind which can also cause touch to get damaged too , to be sure flash with factory/stock ROM and see if things change or remain same

Comment: I've flashed the OEM version of Android on my phone but the problem is still there. I'm now convinced, it's a hardware problem. I don't know what happened all of a sudden. I didn't do any such thing that could damage the touchscreen. It started misbehaving one odd day. :(